# Why is adblocker blocking an ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, adblock

I am using AJAX to check if a username is taken while the user is typing. Opera's adblocker is blocking the script from running. The file path is `http://localhost/flashcardapp/inc/isUidTaken.inc.php?uid=asf`. I can call the file directly, but can't seem to access it with AJAX. When I turn off adblocker, the issue is resolved.

I have tried without effect changing the names of files and folders.

Can I resolve this issue, or should I just leave it as it is, as the server checks if the username is taken as well, the only thing is it would be less convenient if they have to submit the form and then see if their username is taken.

```
$("input[name='uid']").on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "inc/isUidTaken.inc.php",
    data: {
      uid: value
    },
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: AdBlock cant block your php, it's the javascript part of you ajax call it's blocking. I'm guessing because the url has 'flash' in it

Comment: Adblock has an Option to show you the blocked Elements, and the rule that is responsible for each blocked Element. Can't check how this option is called in english, but for me it is `Ctrl+Shift+V`.

Comment: OP is using Opera's built-in blocker

Comment: I think @Martijn is right regarding the URL. I was doing a JSONP call to referrer.json. It was strange because other JSONP calls were working. I changed the name from referrer.json to foo.json as a test and it worked. So, while the call itself was okay the URL was hitting a blacklist.